# How to add multiple toolbars in a single window in win32 program?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, toolbar

I am using [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create a toolbar in my overlapped window using **TOOLBARCLASSNAME** as the window class.
But when i create multiple toolbar windows using createwindowex, the two created windows are both placed in the same area of the window(one overlaps the other).
Also, i can't find a way to provide the position of the toolbars in x-y coordinates.

How do i add two toolbars in the same window such that they don't overlap each other?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you use the Coolbar/Rebar control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997549.aspx

This will allow you to create multiple toolbars with far more ease, plus the benefit of adding a bunch of functionality to your application for your users.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set CCS_NOPARENTALIGN in the style parameter when creating the toolbar window (and perhaps CCS_NORESIZE).